# CSS hack for no-svg support browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

My code:

Kiwi Corp

```
.logo {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 82px;
  background: url(kiwi.svg);
  background-size: 100px 82px;
}
```

How to make a rule for browsers that does not support SVG ?

There is a way through the library Modernizr

```
.main-header {
  background: url(logo.svg) no-repeat top left;
  background-size: contain;
}

.no-svg .main-header {
    background-image: url(logo.png);
}
```

Is there a way without this library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers, that support svg, also support multiple backgrounds, so you can do this:

```
.logo {
  background: url(kiwi.png);
  background: none, url(kiwi.svg);
}
```

Comment: Ah, and a warning: old androids (2.3) support multiple backgrounds but not SVG, so if you care about older android version, use modernizr instead.

Answer (score 2):

make a `.js` file (example `failsvg.js`) load at the end of the html document

your `failsvg.js` looks like (where `yoursvgfile.svg` is your svg document `#loadsvg` is the div where you want to load your svg in html)

```
$(function(){

    $("#loadsvg").load('yoursvgfile.svg',function(response){

        $(this).addClass("svgLoaded");

        if(!response){ // Error loading SVG
            $(this).html('Error loading SVG. Be sure you are running from a the http protocol (not locally)');
// or custom addition here
        }

    });
});
```

and in your css for all svg related elements

```
.svgLoaded #logo {

}
```